# issues using jQuery sliding menu after page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a "mobile-friendly" version of my current website. I am using jQuery mobile api to make the change a little easier.

I am using a button which when pressed executes a jQuery function which uses .animate(); to make the menu slide in from the left.

The script works, however I am having issues when navigating between pages. After using the menu to go to a different page from the one you are currently on, the jQuery no longer executes the function until you reload the new page.

To see what I am talking about, [visit my site](http://m.rgmotorhomehire.com/) and have a fiddle around with the menu at the top left corner.

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({left: "0px"}, 200);

    $('body').animate({left: "285px"}, 200);
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({left: "-285px"}, 200);

    $('body').animate({left: "0px"}, 200);
  });

  $('.menu-item').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({left: "-285px"}, 200);

    $('body').animate({left: "0px"}, 200);

    });
});
```

It's a bit of a mystery to me. Reloading the document works, but it is not a very elegant solution if I must reload the document once every time it loads.

Any other solutions or insights?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making each section of your site a div that slides or fades in after clicking one of the menu tabs instead of each being its own html file.

Comment: interesting.. Would be pretty good looking as well. I'll definitely look into this if there isn't a more straight forward solution :)